# Why Cygwin can't find installed modules of python on windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cygwin, installation

After clean installation of Windows 10, I installed Python 3.7.1, and at the end of installation I chose to add it to Path Variables, which was asked in the options if I want to. Then I installed Cygwin, after which I did pip install --something inside Cygwin. But When I tried to import that module it throwed error cant find module.What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the installation and that does not work. If you need Python inside cygwin use its own version.

The last version of Cygwin Python 3 is 3.6.4-1
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/python3/python3-3.6.4-1

If you need to upgrade the Windows installation run pip from outside the Cygwin enviroment